# AFNetwork with ASP.net Web service

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking

I call my webservice using the getPath method like so:

```
[[AFTwitterAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"GetWineCategoryList"
                                parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
                                    NSLog(@"JSON = %@",JSON);
                                    NSMutableArray *mutableTweets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[JSON count]];
                                    for (NSDictionary *attributes in mutableTweets) {
                                        Tweet *tweet = [[Tweet alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
                                        [mutableTweets addObject:tweet];
                                    }

                                    if (block) {
                                        block([NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableTweets], nil);
                                    }
                                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                    if (block) {
                                        block([NSArray array], error);
                                    }
                                }];
```

It always outputs as NSData. If I convert this NSData to a string I get a JSON String.

```
JSON = <5b7b2243 61746567 6f72794e 616d6522 3a224f54 48455222 7d2c7b22 43617465 676f7279 4e616d65 223a2252 4544227d 2c7b2243 61746567 6f72794e 616d6522 3a22524f 5345227d 2c7b2243 61746567 6f72794e 616d6522 3a225748 49544522 7d5d>
```

Why won't it convert to an NSArray?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NSJSONSerialization Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your NSData object to an NSArray.

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON 
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:&error];
```

This assumes you know that your JSON is of array type and not dictionary type.

Comment: Yeah that works but shouldn't AFNetwork automatically do this for me. I used the same method on Twitter's API and it worked perfectly

Comment: AFNetworking doesn't have any knowledge of what format the response will be, which is why you are given the response as raw data (NSData).  It is up to you to convert it appropriately.

Comment: To get it to work automatically don't you need to use the JSON-specific subclasses in AFNetwork?